# Unable to upload object to S3 with AES server side encryption

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to upload an object to `S3` bucket through `Java` API. However no matter what I do it throws `Access Denied` exception

```
private static void serverSideEncryption() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    AmazonS3 S3_CLIENT = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                              .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                                              .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                                              .build();
    PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, "dfsdf.ss",
            new File("/Users/fsdfs/Desktop/test.jpeg"));
    S3_CLIENT.putObject(putRequest);
    System.out.println("Object uploaded");
}
```

when I run this I get

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: AD1105A291B609D8; S3 Extended Request ID: Ls5wbbW2Yd43p75MJGSOjex0KvmgPiqNBupxpCcEvdMRkK4iptNPNCEwyOqokA=), S3 Extended Request ID: Ls5wbbW2Yd43p75MJGSOje70iqNBupxpCcEvdMRkK4iptNPNCEwyOqokA=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1632)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4365)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4312)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1755)
    at com.xxx.aws.s3.S3Service.serverSideEncryption(S3Service.java:72)
    at com.xxx.aws.s3.S3Service.main(S3Service.java:58)
```

However if I do the same thing from `AWS CLI` using

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket zzz-yyy-xxx --key test/testfdf --server-side-encryption AES256
```

It works perfectly fine.

I also tried the code below

```
private static void serverSideEncryption() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KEY_GENERATOR = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    KEY_GENERATOR.init(256, new SecureRandom());
    SSE_KEY = new SSECustomerKey(KEY_GENERATOR.generateKey());
    AmazonS3 S3_CLIENT = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                              .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                                              .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                                              .build();
    PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, "dfsdf.ss",
            new File("/Users/xx-xx/Desktop/dfdf.jpeg")).withSSECustomerKey(SSE_KEY);
    S3_CLIENT.putObject(putRequest);
    System.out.println("Object uploaded");
}
```

My bucket policy is set to AES encryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your bucket name and access keys are correct, 403 means the key does not exist. This could mean the key as in the bucket name or your access key.

Check both to be sure.

Edit: Following the AWS S3 SSE Documentation at
    https://atdocs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingJavaSDK.html

In order to upload an object with server side encryption it is required to use the`ObjectMetaData`method to specify server side encryption keys, the reference of this object can then be used as a parameter within a `PutObjectRequest`.

Modifications attributed to OP https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629109/damien-amen

Comment: I'm using the same access ID and secret key in the `AWS CLI`. It works perfectly fine. But when I use the same access ID and secret key in java it throws 403.

Comment: Check the BUCKET_NAME variable matches the actual 'Key' name of the bucket you are trying to post too. 403 usually means that Bucket does not exist.

Comment: Where can I get the " actual 'Key' name of the bucket" ?

Comment: So within AWS the name of the bucket as a response is usually designated as the key. So the key of 'BUCKET_NAME' is the actual name of the s3 Bucket on AWS. A 403 response usually means the 'key' or the bucket you are trying to access does not exist. So double check the actual data within the String BUCKET_NAME matches the name of the bucket you want to post data too.

Comment: I checked and it matches :(

Comment: I take it you have followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingJavaSDK.html

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue. The issue was I need to use `ObjectMetaData` method as in the link you provided. Otherwise it's not working. Can you pls modify your answer so that I can mark it as accepted?